# php mysql_fetch_object endless turning

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

```
<? 
$DBAlanadi = "SELECT * FROM Alanadi";
$ACAlanadi = mysql_query($DBAlanadi);
$TotalAlanadi = mysql_num_rows($ACAlanadi);
$Alanadi = mysql_fetch_object($ACAlanadi);

if($TotalAlanadi!=0): 
     while( $Fiyat=$Alanadi ): 
         echo '<a>'.$Fiyat->fiyat.'</a>'; 
     endwhile; 
 endif;
 mysqli_free_result($Alanadi); ?>
```

[image]

line 1 is only endlessly turning

but

I want
40 TL 35 TL 50 TL

Comment: Where do you call `mysqli_fetch_object`?

Comment: $DBAlanadi = "SELECT * FROM Alanadi";
 $ACAlanadi = mysql_query($DBAlanadi);
 $TotalAlanadi = mysql_num_rows($ACAlanadi);
 $Alanadi = mysql_fetch_object($ACAlanadi);

Comment: You're not calling it in the loop, so you're just using the same row over and over.

Comment: What should I do for the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `mysql_fetch_object()` each time through the loop. Otherwise you're just processing the first row over and over.

```
<? 
$DBAlanadi = "SELECT * FROM Alanadi";
$ACAlanadi = mysql_query($DBAlanadi);
$TotalAlanadi = mysql_num_rows($ACAlanadi);

if($TotalAlanadi!=0): 
     while( $Fiyat= mysql_fetch_object($ACAlanadi) ): 
         echo '<a>'.$Fiyat->fiyat.'</a>'; 
     endwhile; 
 endif;
 mysql_free_result($Alanadi); 
?>
```

BTW, the `mysql` extension has been deprecated for many years, and has been totally removed from the current version of PHP. You should convert to `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible.

And you can't call `mysqli_free_result` when the result is from `mysql`, you have to use `mysql_free_result`.

See [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)